# and и or вместо && и ||

Tags: c++, keyword

Недавно был изрядно удивлён, увидев в коде вместо привычных `&&` и `||` ключевые слова `and` и `or`. Возникает вопрос: почему они так редко используются, ведь читаемость, очевидно, выше, а разницы, судя по документации, никакой?

Comment: *читаемость, очевидно, выше* - ой не очевидно...

Comment: Ну язык C появился в начале 70х, а and и or появились в стандарте языка 1999. думаете те, кто пишут учебники быстро переучатся, да и зачем собственно, все уже привыкли

Comment: BTW, `and_eq` и `or_eq` у меня ассоциируются исключительно с "и равно" и "или равно", а не с битовыми операциями :-)

Comment: Если не нравятся `? || && -> *` и т.п. то может просто стоит использовать другой язык? (а мы просто к ним привыкли и полюбили такие компактные обозначения)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как говорится, привычка - вторая натура.:)

Дело в том, что в C эти токены не являются ключевыми словами. Они являются макросами, которые определены в заголовочном файле `<iso646.h>`. Поэтому для их использования нужно включать этот файл, что добавляет работу программистам.:)

Если же вы пишите программы только на C++, то использование этих ключевых слов порой делает код более читабельным. Например, лично я давно взял на вооружение писать `not` вместо оператора отрицания `!`, так как последний порой трудно различим в выражениях, содержащих многочисленные скобки.

Чтобы не быть голословным, приведу ссылку на [мой ответ на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393035/write-a-program-that-uses-bubble-sort-to-sort-integers-in-a-2-dimensional-array/39393312#39393312), где в функции пузырьковой сортировки я использую ключевое слово `not`.

Ключевые слова `and` и `or` - также хорошие кандидаты по включению их в свой арсенал при написании логических выражений. Я их тоже порой использую.:)

Comment: and и or не рекомендуется тем, кто параллельно работает с перлом как минимум :)

Comment: @PinkTux Я думаю, что Perl никак не оказывает влияние на то, как писать код в C++.

Comment: Ещё как оказывает. И наоборот. особенно когда работа не просто параллельная, а совместная (например, xs). Буковки-то одни и те же, но смысл разный. Впрочем, если нет проблем мгновенного переключения контекста в голове, то писать можно что угодно и как угодно...

Comment: @PinkTux  Это всего лишь частный случай, когда один и тот же программист в равной мере загружен C++ и Perl и должен объединять объектные модули, написанные на этих языках, в один проект. Что касается C++ и C то их развитие согласуется комитетами по стандартизации, и это обычное дело, когда в одном проекте программисту требуется писать код на C++ и C.

Comment: *Это всего лишь частный случай, когда один и тот же программист в равной мере загружен C++ и Perl* - разве в первом комментарии я написал что-то принципиально отличное от этого?